# Representation theorem for continuous process of finite variation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

There is a martingale representation theorem

> If $M$ is a continuous $L^2$-martingale, there is a Brownian motion $B$ and a cadlag adapted function $\sigma$ such that
>   $$
> M_t = M_0 + \int_0^t \sigma(B_s)dB_s, \text{ a.s., for all } t \ge 0.
> $$

Is there an equivalent for continuous process of finite variation?
Something like

> If $V$ is a continuous process of finite variation, there is a Brownian motion $B$ and a cadlag adapted function $\mu$ such that
>   $$
> V_t = V_0 + \int_0^t \mu(B_s)ds, \text{ a.s., for all } t \ge 0.
> $$

Comment: The integral $\int_0^t\mu(B_s)\,\mathrm dB_s$ can't be of finite variation, can it?

Comment: @StefanHansen Good point. I meant $ds$ in the integral not $dB_s$. I corrected it.

Comment: 1.  you seem to be absolutely continuous, how about a cantor function   2.  you can have a process like that on a space that does not support a brownian motion, which cannot happen in the contiuous martingale case